# Snapping vectors to vertices for ROI delineation?

Tags: vector, remote-sensing, landsat, envi

I am trying to manually extract a set of ROIs in ENVI 5.0.

However, I can't seem to successfully line up the vector to be flush with the boundary of the pixels, which means I don't have fine-tune control over which pixels are included/excluded at the edge of my vector. Also, the resulting ROI ends up splicing pixels in half.

Is there anyway I can snap the vertices to the pixels when I'm drawing my vectors/ROIs?